# php two diffenrent versions on mac os X

Tags: php

I have Mac OS 10.11.6 (15G31), Version  Apache/2.4.18

in terminal

```
php -v
```

shows that
PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Jul 22 2016 17:18:01)

```
phpinfo()
```

shows 
PHP Version 5.5.36

two different versions, how it could be and how to delete one version?

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer your question, if you want to run multiple PHP versions simply, I'd recommend [PHPBrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew)

Answer (score 0):

type `which php` in your command line to see where your php files (of each version) are located.

If it shows exactly one php directory that's because the other one is not set in your PATH environment variable. It could be found by searching inside httpd.conf